# Java based configuration and scan

Tags: java, spring, configuration

In my xml configuration files I can write

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.my.stuff"/>
```

Now I move on java based configuration. How I can do it in my `@Configuration` based class without having `ApplicationContext` there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [@ComponentScan](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) annotation to your configuration class.

Example :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.acme.app.services")
 public class AppConfig {
     @Bean
     public MyBean myBean() {
         // instantiate, configure and return bean ...
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

In case of spring < 3.1 you can use http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.html in @PostConstruct method of your @Configuration class. Of course you need to autowire ApplicationContext into you @Configuration.